# Java class/bytecode weaving/editing on J2ME?

Tags: java, class, java-me, bytecode

I'm just wondering if there are any Java class editors that work on a J2ME environment. I've looked at aspectwerkz, which works with Java 1.4, but there are some dependencies that doesn't work on J2ME, plus it seems too big for my project. I've also took a look at Objectweb ASM, but it requires Java 5. I've seen other libraries such as BCEL and AspectJ, but none of them seem to work. So basically, I'm looking for a Java library that can modify class files (doesn't matter if it's through bytecode or not) and runs on a J2ME environment. Thanks.

Comment: I found that asm version 3.3.1 works on J2ME and the HelloWorld example worked. I guess I will work with that, but it would be nice to have a "higher" library like AspectJ which can insert raw java code. If nothing like that exists for J2ME, I guess I can make the library myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) looks like it will. See the last page of the tutorial.

Comment: Thank you! I took a look a Javassist before, but it gave me an error "javassist.CannotCompileException: cannot find java.lang.Object" It's most likely because I am using java cvm with many classes preloaded. I just added Object.class to my classpath and it worked. Maybe I'll modify the source to do it better.

Comment: Also, does Javassist support "live-editing". For example, I write a custom class loader that patches the class in memory before loading it, and does not actually touch the class file?

Comment: Are you asking about whether you can modify classes that aren't loaded from class files? If so, I think so; see the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

[Retroweaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/) is something to look at. Since source is available you may be able to modify it to your needs.